# Order of filling electrons in Jahn-Teller energy diagram

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

When filling electrons in atomic or molecular orbitals we fill first the lower energy orbitals and then the higher, according to Pauli and Hund's rule. But this seem not to be the case when considering metal complexes. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahn%E2%80%93Teller_effect)[image: Wikipedia]

For example why the $d_{xy}$ orbital in the $d^4$ high spin is not fully occupied? Is the pairing energy that changes the order of filling the orbitals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just an illustrative example. The tendency of a complex to favor low-spin or high-spin configurations is dictated by the relative magnitudes of the pairing energy, P, and the splitting energy, $\Delta$, between $e_g$ and $t_{2g}$.*

If $\Delta$ is greater than the energy required to pair two electrons, then electrons pair in $t_{2g}$ before occupying $e_g$. In the example you've shown of compression, this would be the $d_{xy}$ orbital.

*For octahedral complexes. Jahn-Teller can also happen for tetrahedral complexes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the fact that a complex is low or high spin affect the way of ordering after the Jahn-Teller distortion? For example considering compression for $d^4$ low spin. Should now the $d_{xy}$ be fully occupied?

Comment: @adosar exactly.  In the compression example, $d_{xy}$ would be doubly occupied, defining the $d^4$ low spin configuration.

Comment: But we can't predict if elongation or compression will happen right? Also when filling atomic orbitals or molecular we neglect pairing energy because it is negligible compared to $\Delta E$ of the orbitals?

Comment: @adosar I only mentioned compression because I could name the exact orbital. In the case of elongation and $\Delta$ larger than the pairing energy, then you'd have an electron go into either $d_{xz}$ or $d_{xy}$ as they are degenerate.

Comment: @adosar the pairing energy is exactly what we are comparing to the $\Delta$, so you definitely do not ignore it :)

Comment: At first I thought you were asking a very astute question about the stabilizing effects from parallel spin (due to exchange symmetry). This is present in the system so you'd really be comparing $\Delta - V$ to the pairing energy, where V is the parallel spin coupling. However, inorganic chemists typically ignore this effect as it is very small for parallel electrons of very different energy.

Comment: Two more questions and I accept the answer. Why we don't care about pairing energy when we look at electronic configurations of ground states? Is it so small? I learned the term pairing energy in inorganic chemistry. I didn't hear it even in physical chemistry. Also why the low spin or high spin determines the ordering after Jahn-Teller distorion if the energy levels have changed and $\Delta$ has also changed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the confusion may be in how the pairing energy is defined. It is the energy required to place two electrons in the same orbital, and it is not ignored. What is typically ignored is the stabilizing effect of parallel spins in the high spin case (see my previous comment)

Comment: @adosar did this clear things up?

Comment: So after Jahn-Teller distortion the difference between $\Delta$ and pairing energy is the same and the filling order is the same as before the distortion?

Comment: There are two things at play here. $\Delta$ vs pairing energy is what determines whether the high-spin or the low-spin configuration is lower in energy (and therefore occupied by the complex). Jahn-Teller just occurs in certain configurations to lower the energy of the molecule by distorting its geometry to break symmetry. See the bottom figure you posted as an example of when Jahn-Teller distortions wouldn't lower the energy of the complex.